# How do I tar node modules in different directories?

Tags: unix, tar

I want to cache node modules for each submodule. How can I do so? For example I have the following directory structure:

```
/test1/node_modules
/test2/node_modules
```

How do I tar each node module directory under the main directory so that I can then have a zip file with the following structure

```
/test1/node_modules
/test2/node_modules
```

### edit

What I mean is that I want to get all the node_modules directories under the main directory. node_modules directory can be under directory test1 or test2 or test3. I want to get them all and zip them, maintaining the directory structure. So in the zip file they will be `test1/node_modules`,  `test2/node_modules`

... but I also want a "catch all" solution... every `node_modules` dir should be in my tar.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear where you're blocked. Here is how I would do it:

### Use 2 distinct commands, one to create, one to add:

```
# create my.tar
tar cf my.tar /test1/node_modules/*

# add second directory with tar uf
tar uf my.tar /test2/node_modules/*
```

If you have more than `test1` & `test2`, but want to have all `test` dirs:

```
tar cf my.tar /test*/node_modules/
```

If you want every `node_modules`, then use a find command, piped to your tar command

```
find / -type d -name node_modules | xargs tar cf my.tar
```

Comment: What I mean is that I want to get all the node_modules directories under the main directory. node_modules directory can be under directory test1 or test2 or test3. I want to get them all and zip them, maintaining the directory structure. So in the zip file they will be test1/node_modules, test2/node_modules

Comment: Is there a catch all solution?

Comment: I want all the node_modules directories. Not all directories that contain node_modules will start with the word "test"

Comment: does the command find / -type d -name node_modules | xargs tar cf my.tar protect the directory structure of the node_modules

Comment: Yes it should do what I understood you wanted. 
Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have these node_modules

```
➦  tree ./
./
├── pack.js
├── test1
│   └── node_modules
│       └── a
└── test2
    └── node_modules
        └── b

4 directories, 3 files
```

You can use node script to pack files. `/^test\d+/` means test1 test2 test3 etc.

```
'use strict';

const fstream = require('fstream');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const tar = require('tar');
const path = require('path');

const dist = path.join(__dirname, 'all.tgz');

fstream.Reader({
  path: __dirname,
  filter() {
    return this.path === __dirname ||
      path.relative(__dirname, this.path).match(/^test\d+/);
  },
})
.pipe(tar.Pack({ fromBase: true }))
.pipe(zlib.createGzip())
.pipe(fstream.Writer(dist));
```

Run `node pack.js` and all node_modules directories will be in one file all.tgz.

`vim all.tgz`

```
" tar.vim version v29
" Browsing tarfile
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

/
test1/
test1/node_modules/
test1/node_modules/a
test2/
test2/node_modules/
test2/node_modules/b
```